# Can I add VS2012 Buttons to Build in Debug vs. Release?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I would like to be able to hit a button or keystroke that switches to a particular solution configuration (say, Release) and then builds in that configuration. I have been unable to find a way to do so. Does something like this exist?

Comment: you can change the configuration first and then build

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't obvious in the question, but that is what I don't want to do. I would like to eliminate the extra step.

Comment: sounds like a feature request then.  you can use this: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: The reason I asked here is that people know things. I was hoping that someone here would be able to offer options or suggestions, or how to approach developing it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it should be fairly easy to do as a [Visual Studio Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5abkeks7.aspx).  Add-ins are one of the lighter-weight ways to extend Visual Studio.  You'll probably want to look into:

- [How to create an add in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/80493a3w.aspx)
- [How to add your add-in to a toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165627.aspx).  You could also create your own dedicated toolbar if you wish.
- When your command gets called, you probably need to set the [ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.configurationmanager.activeconfiguration.aspx) property to your desired configuration or the [SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.solutionbuild.activeconfiguration.aspx) property (you'll have to play around to see which one does what you want).  Note that this does change the state of VS, so it may fire some other events in the IDE that happen when the build configuration changes.
- Then, just invoke the build as a named command (e.g. `DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.BuildSolution")`).  IIRC, invoking this way is synchronous, so when control returns to your code, the build will be complete.
- Set the configuration back to how it was before to clean up after yourself.